# Apply Steam Overlay to Chrome?

Tags: steam, windows, controllers

I got Chrome to launch from Steam in kiosk mode by using `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://www.netflix.com/browse --kiosk --user-data-dir="C:/AppData/SteamChrome"` (in this case with Netflix) Is there any way to enable the Steam Overlay? Steam Controller bindings won't toggle without it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you allow Steam-Community ingame for Chrome in Steam-Library?

If you didnt, go to your libraray -> press right mouse button on Chrome -> select the tab **properties** -> tick the option: **allow Steam-Community in game**